# Trying to pass adress to a reffernce to a pointer

Tags: c++, rvalue

Why calling funk(&a) gives a compile error

```
func(int * & data) {data++;}

int main(){

int a = 5;
int *p = &a;
func(&a); //this gives a compile error
funk(p);  //this works fine 
}
```

error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘int*&’ from an rvalue of type ‘int*’

Comment: `funk(p); ` where is this function defined?

Comment: because `a` is of type constant (address can't be changed). you can't change `a` address(which you are doing inside the function).

Comment: You cannot modify an _rvalue_.  That is what `func(&a)` is attempting.  When you pass a reference, it must be either an _lvalue_ or have a _const-qualifier_.

Comment: @paddy actually rvalues can be modified. Example `std::string().resize(5);` . This code is illegal because it attempts to bind an lvalue reference to an rvalue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as the error message explains, the parameter needs to reference a variable, and `&a` is not a variable, it's *an address* of a variable.